# RegDBQueryKey cannot list keys for 32- and 64-bit keys at the same time

Tags: registry, 64-bit, 32-bit, installscript

I have been facing a problem in InstallScript to get the list of registry keys for 32- and 64-bit installations.

My machine is Windows Server 2008 64-bit.  I can install the SQL Server 2008 32-bit version or 64-bit version on this machine.

Now during the setup I need to know whether either of the SQL Server versions are installed.

As per my understanding,

- 64-bit applications on 64-bit machine are stored in `Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall`.
- 32-bit applications on 64-bit machine are stored in `Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall`.

I have written a function which should search both these locations for SQL Server installation using the `RegDBQueryKey` function.

Even if I pass `"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"` to `RegDBQueryKey`, it lists the keys of `Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall`.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set this flag before your call to RegDBQueryKey:

```
REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY;
```

That will disable the default forwarding to the 64-bit version of the key, and give you the 32-bit version.  It applies globally, so when you're done make sure to reset the flag using:

```
REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTION_USE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS;
```

Comment: +1 for the bottom line...as well as the reminder to _reset the flag when done_.  The problem I encountered that led me to this question and answer stemmed from failure to do just that!